# Why it is better to use interfaces in Web Services?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Why it is better to use interface to implement in Web Services(JAX-WS)?

What are the advantages? and if we do not use interface, what disadvantages (especially on the client)?

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces are a contract, so you can design them to represent what your objects can do, and how they can be used by developers.
They are their an agreed approach between the publisher and the consumer. Once agreed they should be changed only on agreement by everyone to prevent breaking changes.
For web services you can fully map out your services to the outside world by creating an extensive set of interfaces that cover all your requirements without the baggage of implementation concerns.